# Get all style rules in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, stylesheet

Is there a way to get all the CSS rules that are applied to a page? Currently, I'm using jQuery to do it, but is there a server side solution?

```
var style = "";

//grab all styles defined on the page
$("style").each(function () {
    style += $(this).html() + "\n";
});

$.ajaxSetup({ async: false });
//grab all styles referenced by stylesheet links on the page
$("[rel=stylesheet]").each(function () {
    $.get(this.href, '', function (data) {
        style += data + "\n";
    });
});
$.ajaxSetup({async: true});
style = "<style type='text/css'>" + style + "</style>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `HtmlHead.StyleSheet` property

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlhead.stylesheet.aspx